# How to use ScriptModule on Framework 4 in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-config

I want to use ASP.NET with jquery ajax post, which requires adding the following to web.config:

```
<httpModules>           
     <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/> 
</httpModules>
```

When I add it to web.config of application using framework 4.0 the application doesn`t work and I get a 500 - Internal server error and when I remove the code above the application works perfectly.

Is there anything I`m missing (add a refference or something)?!!!

Comment: this works for me: `<add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>`

Comment: did you tried with another publickeytoken ?